# get all document using firebase cloud function and get it from flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

how can i get all documents using firebase cloud function (javascript) and use it in flutter.

my code in firebase cloud function

```
exports.getAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const usersRef = db.collection("users");

  usersRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
    const users = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      users.push(doc.data());
    });
    res.status(200).send(users);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

my code in flutter

```
Future<void> callGetAllUsersFunction() async {
    try {
      final HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getAllUsers');
      final HttpsCallableResult<dynamic> result = await callable.call();

      if (result.data != null) {

        print(result.data.toString());
      } else {
        
        print('Aucun utilisateur trouvé.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      
      print('Erreur lors de l\'appel de la Firebase Function : $error');
    }
  }
```

all documents using firebase cloud function (javascript) and use it in flutter.